# How to execute a procedure from PL/SQL via Firebird through a DB link?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, firebird, dblink

I created a DB link between Oracle and Firebird. I can select tables with this query :

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM city_TB@firebird_dblink
```

I need to use packages and view. When I use this query;

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM city@firebird_dblink
```

no rows are returned, because `city` is a view. There is a procedure to show query results for views and packages. After connecting the system, IBExpert executes this procedure, then I can see the view and package results. I need to execute the same procedure in PLSQL. I tried this piece of code. But, it throws

> PLS-00201: identifier 'AUTHENTICATION.LOGIN_DEV@FIREBIRD_DBLINK' must be declared.

How can I execute this procedure?

```
BEGIN
  authentication.login_dev@firebird_dblink;
END;
```

[image: IBExpert DB Properties]

Comment: I can connect Firebird db and execute the same procedure from Python.

Comment: Try `schema.package.procedure@dblink`. Oracle resolves package name to schema name if you use `package.procedure`

Comment: Thank you @astentx. I will try. But, How can I get the scheme name?

Comment: Are you using the devart Firebird ODBC driver for this? You could also try contacting their support to see if this is actually possible and supported.

Comment: No, I am not using Devart.

Comment: I would suggest to use DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH package.

Comment: Thank you. I tried a lot. I face so many errors. I think that is not common.
DECLARE
   result VARCHAR2(100);
   cur    NUMBER;
BEGIN
   cur := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.OPEN_CURSOR@firebird_dblink_3;
   DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.PARSE@firebird_dblink_3(cur, 'EXECUTE PROCEDURE authentication.login_dev');
   DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_NON_QUERY@firebird_dblink_3(cur);
   DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.CLOSE_CURSOR@firebird_dblink_3(cur);
END;